# Generate a Unit Circle Trigonometry

Tags: graphics, labeling, trigonometry, mapthread

Struggling often with Trigonometry I would like to have some code to generate this Unit Circle Trigonometry. Would be of great help when I need to transform some data :

[image]

Comment: Is your question: how to create this figure in Mathematica?  Can you please describe what you tried so far and where you got stuck?  You've been using Mathematica for a while, so to avoid the repliers spend too much time on writing up what you can already do yourself, please focus on the detail which you really couldn't solve.

Comment: Is your question just how to generate this exact figure in Mathematica?  Why would you need to, if you already have the figure you included in the question?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are a couple tricky points here.  Here's a start, which I imagine you can finish.

```
markings[t_] := Module[{o={0,0},p={Cos[t],Sin[t]}, 
  t2=Together[t],tFormat, rot},
  tFormat = If[Denominator[t2]=!=1, 
    Row[{Numerator[t2],"/",Denominator[t2]}]];
  rot = If[TrueQ[Pi/2<Mod[t,2Pi]<3Pi/2],t+Pi,t];
    {{Opacity[0.3],Line[{o,p}]},
     Rotate[Inset[Style[
       Row[{t(180/Pi)Degree, " = ",tFormat}],
     FontSize->18], p/2],rot], 
     Text[{Cos[t],Sin[t]},p,-1.3p]}
];
Graphics[{
  Circle[{0,0},1],
  Table[markings[t],{t,{Pi/6,Pi/4,2Pi/3}}]
}]
```

[image]

In addition to finishing it, logical enhancements would include: Making the Circle thicker, adjusting the size and/or format of the point labels, adding Points on the boundary, and/or making it dynamic.

Have fun!

Comment: Ooh! Making it dynamic would be interesting. (and, you already got my +1)

Comment: @Mark, Thank you very much !

Comment: doesn't `tFormat` need to include how the thing should look if the condition is False, i.e., unaltered `t2`? Or was that the thing for 500 to work out on his own?

Answer (score 42):

Here's a dynamic version (sorry, I couldn't resist).

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{alist, pt, pc},
  pt[a_] := {Cos[a], Sin[a]};
  alist = 
   Union[Range[0, 2 Pi - Pi/6, Pi/6], Range[0, 2 Pi - Pi/4, Pi/4]];
  a = Nearest[alist, Mod[ArcTan @@ p, 2 Pi, 0]][[1]];
  pc = pt[a];

  Graphics[{
    Circle[],
    {LightGray, Line[{{0, 0}, pt[#]}] & /@ alist},
    {PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[pt /@ alist]},
    {AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{0, 0}, pc}]},
    {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pc]},
    Text[pc, pc, -2 pc],
    Text[Framed[Row[{a/Pi/2 360, "\[Degree] = ", a}], 
      Background -> White, FrameStyle -> None], pc/2, {0, 0}, 
     pt[Mod[a, Pi, -Pi/2]]]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]],
 {{p, {1, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
 {{a, 0}, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If only I would have thought of that! :)

Comment: @Heike, Thank You so much. This is so cool !

Comment: @Heike Very nice. Perhaps we should all upvote a question that generates such pleasing answers... Funny that this Q still has 0 votes at the moment.

Comment: +1 for aesthetics (white background on the text, etc...)

Comment: @cormullion The question actually currently has two Upvotes and two Downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for this, and all my students thank you... I had a nice unit circle,  but yours is even nicer!

Comment: @Heike Unless I am mistaken, your (nice) code has a defective default starting value, resulting in `ArcTan::indet: "Indeterminate expression tan^-1(0.,0.) encountered"` which is sorted out as soon as one picks an angle.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cpts[r_Real, a_List] := {r Cos[#], r Sin[#]} & /@ a

rmain = 1;
anglesRadians = # + {0, π/6, π/4, π/3} & /@ 
    Range[0, 3 π/2, π/2] // Flatten;
(*anglesRadians=Range[0,2π,π/12];*) 
anglesDegrees = anglesRadians (180/π);
coords = (StringForm["(``,``)", Cos[#], Sin[#]] & /@ anglesRadians);
tancoords = (StringForm["``", Tan[#]] & /@ anglesRadians) /. 
   ComplexInfinity -> ∞;
labels = Rotate[#, 
       If[π/2 < Last@# < 3 π/2, Last@# + π, Last@#]] & /@ 
     TraditionalForm[#] & /@ (StringForm["``° = `` rad", 
       First@#, Last@#] & /@ 
     Transpose[{anglesDegrees, anglesRadians}] );

ListPlot[Evaluate@MapThread[Callout[#1, Style[#2, 12]
     (*,CalloutMarker\[Rule]"CirclePoint"*)
     (*,CalloutStyle\[Rule]Blue*)
     , LeaderSize -> {12, ArcTan @@ #1, 4}] &
   , {cpts[1.0 rmain, anglesRadians], coords}
   ]
 , PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red}
 , PlotRange -> {{ -rmain, rmain}, {- rmain, rmain}}
 (* PlotRange for the tangent ring *)
 (*{{ -1.4rmain,1.4rmain},{ -1.4rmain,1.4rmain}}*) 
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Axes -> False
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.12], Scaled[0.12]}
 , Epilog -> {
   {Thin, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@
     cpts[0.4 rmain, anglesRadians]}
   , {Thin, Dashed, MapThread[Line[{#1, #2}] &
     , {cpts[0.8 rmain, anglesRadians]
      , cpts[1.0 rmain, anglesRadians]}
     ]}
   , {MapThread[Text[Style[#1, 12, Blue], #2] &
     , {labels, cpts[0.6 rmain, anglesRadians]}] }
   
   (*--------------------------------*)
   (* enable only if an annulus with Tan() values  is required
   , expect to do some tinkering to fonts/plotrange *)
   
   (*,{FaceForm[{Opacity[0.2,Nest[Lighter,Brown,1]]}]
   ,EdgeForm[{Dashed,Black}]
   ,Annulus[{0,0},{1.5rmain,1.75rmain}]}
   ,{ MapThread[Text[Style[#1,11,Black],#2]&
   ,{tancoords,cpts[1.62 rmain,anglesRadians]}]}*)
   
   (*--------------------------------*)
   }
 , Prolog -> {
   {FaceForm[Nest[Lighter, Cyan, 3]], EdgeForm[{Dashed, Black}], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, rmain]}
   }
 ]
```

[image]

---

**Usage notes**

1. `rmain` is the radius of the main circle. If the user chooses a value other than `1`, it would still work, but then the user must keep the `Axes` and `Frame` turned off or else the labels would not make much sense.
2. The function `cpts` generates points around the main circle for the list of angles. This is used many times while plotting various primitives.
3. I wanted to use `Callout`, so resorted to `ListPlot`.
4. An `Annulus` that displays `Tan[θ]` values can be enabled by un-commenting the indicated code lines.

Comment: very nice! ... (don't mind the ... I just had to `PadRight` :-) )