# Text Offset Question

Tags: plotting

There is an absolutely wonderful answer by Heike at [Generate a Unit Circle Trigonometry](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/generate-a-unit-circle-trigonometry). It is an answer that will lead me to a lot of learning.

Here is my playing with her code:

```
Graphics[{
  Circle[],
  {LightGray, Line[{{0, 0}, pt[#]}] & /@ alist},
  PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[pt /@ alist],
  Text[pt[5 Pi/6], pt[5 Pi/6], -2 pt[5 Pi/6], Background -> Yellow],
  Text[pt[Pi/6], pt[Pi/6], -2 pt[Pi/6], Background -> Yellow],
  Red, PointSize[Large],
  Point[-2 pt[Pi/6]],
  Point[-2 pt[5 Pi/6]],
  }]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Now I worked through the examples in the documentation for the Text command and found that:

```
Graphics[{
  Text[Framed["ABCDEF"], {0, 0}, {-1, -1}],
  Circle[]
  }, Axes -> True, Ticks -> None]
```

Puts the lower left corner of the textbook at the origin:

[image]

But then I am not sure why this moves the textbook as it does.

```
Graphics[{
  Text[Framed["ABCDEF"], {0, 0}, {-2, -1}],
  Circle[]
  }, Axes -> True, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Then, of course, I'd like to get back to the brilliant code by Heike, and understand how his labels work so wonderfully in my first block of code above.

I'd like to be able to understand this so well that I can explain it to my students and to faculty in one of my Mathematica sessions.

Comment: For a long time now (version 6?) `Text` has just been a proxy for [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) so if you want to really understand it look at that documentation instead.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to use the 2nd argument of `Text` to do all the positioning and to use its 3rd argument for aligning. That is I treat `Text` as having the formal arguments

```
Text[expression, position, alignment]
```

I define the following constants for convenience.

```
align[Right] = {1, 0};
align[Center] = {0, 0} ;(* default *)
align[Left] = {-1, 0};
```

Here's how it works in practice. I will draw a disk and put two lines of text below it.

Without a 3rd argument, the text is centered, the default alignment.

```
Module[{center, r, dy},
  center = {0.5, 0.7};
  r = .2;
  dy = -.1;
  Graphics[
    {Red, Disk[Scaled[center], Scaled[r]],
     Black,
       Text["A short line", Scaled[center + {0, -r + dy}]], 
       Text["A much longer line of text", Scaled[center + {0, -r + 2 dy}]]},
    Frame -> True,
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]]
```

[image: example1]

But it would look better if it were left justified, so I use the 3rd argument.

```
Module[{center, r, dy},
  center = {0.5, 0.7};
  r = .2;
  dy = -.1;
  Graphics[
   {Red, Disk[Scaled[center], Scaled[r]],
    Black,
     Text["A short line", Scaled[center + {0, -r + dy}], align[Left]], 
     Text["A much longer line of text", Scaled[center + {0, -r + 2 dy}], align[Left]]},
   Frame -> True,
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]]
```

[image: example2]

The text is now properly justified but it needs to be shifted to left by the radius of the disk. So I adjust the position using the 2nd argument.

```
Module[{center, r, dy},
  center = {0.5, 0.7};
  r = .2;
  dy = -.1;
  Graphics[
   {Red, Disk[Scaled[center], Scaled[r]],
    Black,
     Text["A short line", Scaled[center + {-r, -r + dy}], align[Left]], 
     Text["A much longer line of text", Scaled[center + {-r, -r + 2 dy}], align[Left]]},
   Frame -> True,
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]]
```

[image: example3]

Now the text looks as I wish it to. I often find this way of working with `Text` useful and convenient.

I do not claim this method fits all situations, but I thought I would bring it to the attention of others who might also find it useful and convenient.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I understand, you want to know, how the 3rd argument of the `Text` works. To me it seems it is answered in the [documentation of the `Text` function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html).

Here is the relevant part:

> `Text[expr,coords,offset]` specifies an offset for the block of text
>   relative to the coordinates given. Giving an offset `{sdx,sdy}` specifies that the
>   point {x,y} should lie at relative coordinates `{sdx,sdy}` within the bounding rectangle
>   that encloses the text. Each **relative coordinate runs from `-1` to `1`** across
>   the bounding rectangle.

If you use the `offset` to `-2` you set the point given by `coords` outside of your element.

Small additional vertical offset is caused by `Framed` and can be removed by adding option `BaselinePostition->{Bottom->Bottom}`.

In the code by Heike he makes use of the fact, that `pt[5 Pi/6]` is vector of coordinates and for the offset he uses this vector for a direction for an additional shift. `-2 pt[5 Pi/6]` is in the relative (to frame size) coordinates of the label pushing the label away from the coordinates of `pt[5 Pi/6]`.